# Finding how many times an instance happens in a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list and my goal is to determine how many times the values in that list goes above a certain value.

For instance if my list is:
        List = {0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4}
Id like to know that there were two instances where my values in the list were greater than 2 and stayed above 2.  So in this case there were 2 instances, since it dropped below 2 at one point and went above it again.

```
    private void Report_GeneratorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Lists
        var current = _CanDataGraph._DataPoints[CanDataGraph.CurveTag.Current].ToList();
        var SOC = _CanDataGraph._DataPoints[CanDataGraph.CurveTag.Soc].ToList();
        var highcell = _CanDataGraph._DataPoints[CanDataGraph.CurveTag.HighestCell].ToList();
        var lowcell = _CanDataGraph._DataPoints[CanDataGraph.CurveTag.LowestCell].ToList();

        //Seperates current list into charging, discharging, and idle
        List<double> charging = current.FindAll(i => i > 2);
        List<double> discharging = current.FindAll(i => i < -2);
        List<double> idle = current.FindAll(i => i < 2 && i > -2);

        //High cell
        List<double> overcharged = highcell.FindAll(i => i > 3.65);
        int ov = overcharged.Count;

        if (ov > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This Battery has gone over Voltage!");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This battery has never been over Voltage.");
        }

        //Low cell
        List<double> overdischarged = lowcell.FindAll(i => i > 3.65);
        int lv = overdischarged.Count;

        if (lv > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This Battery has been overdischarged!");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This battery has never been overdischarged.");
        }


        //Each value is 1 second
        int chargetime = charging.Count;
        int dischargetime = discharging.Count;
        int idletime = idle.Count;


        Console.WriteLine("Charge time: " + chargetime + "s" + "\n" + "Discharge time: " + dischargetime + "s" + "\n" + "Idle time: " + idletime);

    }
```

My current code is this and outputs:

```
    This battery has never been over Voltage.
    This battery has never been overdischarged.
    Charge time: 271s
    Discharge time: 0s
    Idle time: 68
```

Comment: So basically you want  to iterate the values and check for when the previous value is below 2 and the current is above.  Do you count the first value being over 2 as well?

Comment: What is your question?  You've provided your code's output but since we don't have access to your data points (I assume they differ from your `{0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4}` example) we don't know if that output is right or not.

Comment: the data points are very similar to the example i gave it is just a lot longer 1000+ values in each list. So my lists goes from -10 to 10 back in forth many times.  I would like to count how many instances it is above 2 like my example.

Comment: You've provided actual output, which is good, but without giving us either the values used to create that output or the _expected_ output it makes it more difficult to answer this.  In short, which part of your output is not correct?  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) where it says  "Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." and see the link that follows, too.

Answer (score 4):

There are a great many ways to solve this problem; my suggestion is that you break it down into a number of smaller problems and then write a simple method that solves each problem.

Here's a simpler problem: given a sequence of `T`, give me back a sequence of `T` with "doubled" items removed:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveDoubles<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> items) 
{
  T previous = default(T);
  bool first = true;
  foreach(T item in items)
  {
    if (first || !item.Equals(previous)) yield return item;
    previous = item;
    first = false;
  }
}
```

Great. How is this helpful? Because the solution to your problem is now:

```
int count = myList.Select(x => x > 2).RemoveDoubles().Count(x => x);
```

Follow along.

If you have `myList` as `{0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4}` then the result of the `Select` is `{false, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, true}`.

The result of the `RemoveDoubles` is `{false, true, false, true}`.

The result of the `Count` is 2, which is the desired result.

Try to use off-the-shelf parts when you can. If you cannot, try to solve a *simple, general problem* that gets you what you need; now you have a tool you can use for other tasks that require you to remove duplicates in a sequence.

Answer (score 3):

This solution should achieve the desired result.

```
    List<int> lsNums = new List<int>() {0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4} ;
    public void MainFoo(){
        int iChange = GetCritcalChangeNum(lsNums, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("Critical change = %d", iChange);
    }
    public int GetCritcalChangeNum(List<int> lisNum, int iCriticalThreshold) { 
        int iCriticalChange = 0;
        int iPrev = 0;
        lisNum.ForEach( (int ele) => { 
            if(iPrev <= iCriticalThreshold && ele > iCriticalThreshold){
                iCriticalChange++;
            }
            iPrev = ele;
        });

        return iCriticalChange;
    }
```

Comment: Why do a `ToList` just to get the `ForEach` method when this is the same amount of code using regular `foreach`.

Comment: Because his example uses a list not a array and I always use ForEach() for lists. Probably more efficient to use foreach because of pushing and poping stack information but in this case its only being called once so it doesn't matter. @juharr

Comment: @RufusL Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension method as shown below.

```cs
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static int InstanceCount(this List<double> list, Predicate<double> predicate)
    {
        int instanceCount = 0;
        bool instanceOccurring = false;

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                if (!instanceOccurring)
                {
                    instanceCount++;
                    instanceOccurring = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                instanceOccurring = false;
            }
        }

        return instanceCount;
    }
}
```

And use your newly created method like this

```cs
current.InstanceCount(p => p > 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public static int CountOverLimit(IEnumerable<double> items, double limit)
{
    int overLimitCount = 0;
    bool isOverLimit = false;

    foreach (double item in items)
    {
        if (item > limit)
        {
            if (!isOverLimit)
            {
                overLimitCount++;
                isOverLimit = true;
            }
        }
        else if (isOverLimit)
        {
            isOverLimit = false;
        }
    }
    return overLimitCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly concise and readable solution. Hopefully this helps. If the limit is variable, just put it in a function and take the list and the limit as parameters.

```
int [] array = new int [9]{0, 0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4};
List<int> values = array.ToList();

int overCount = 0;
bool currentlyOver2 = false;

for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++) 
{
    if (values[i] > 2)
    {
        if (!currentlyOver2)
            overCount++;

        currentlyOver2 = true;
    }
    else
        currentlyOver2 = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this using `System.Linq` is to walk through the list, selecting both the `item` itself and it's `index`, and return `true` for each item where the item is greater than `value` and the previous item is less than or equal to `value`, and then select the number of `true` results. Of course there's a special case for index `0` where we don't check the previous item:

```
public static int GetSpikeCount(List<int> items, int threshold)
{
    return items?
        .Select((item, index) =>
            index == 0
                ? item > threshold
                : item > threshold && items[index - 1] <= threshold)
        .Count(x => x == true)  // '== true' is here for readability, but it's not necessary
           ?? 0;  // return '0' if 'items' is null
}
```

Sample usage:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var myList = new List<int> {0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4};
    var count = GetSpikeCount(myList, 2);
    // count == 2
}
```